# react map() function in render method is one step later

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, render

There's a thing I can't udsrestand in react why when I pass the props to a component an then doing a map() on them it cames 1 item later? 
here's the code:

```
class ImageInput extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        photos: props.photos
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handleClick() {
    this.inputElement.click();
}


render(){
    const previews = this.state.photos.map((photo, index) => 
        <ImagePreview key={index} preview={photo.preview} name={photo.name} />
    );
    console.log(1, this.state.photos);
    console.log(2, previews);
    return(
        <div className="form-image-field">
            <div className="form-image-input" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                <p className="image-input-title">Add photo</p>
                <p className="image-input-text">Minimum size of 300x300 jpeg jpg png 5 MB</p>
                <input type="file" 
                       accept="image/*" 
                       style={{"display":"none"}}
                       ref={input => this.inputElement = input} 
                       onChange={this.props.handleImage} />
            </div>
            { previews }
        </div>
    );

}
```

after adding first pictire console.log looks like:

```
   1 []0: {file: File, preview: "...", name: "C..."}
     length: 1
   2 []
     length: 0
```

after second one it's:

```
1 [{…}]0: {file: File, preview: "...", name: "..."}
       1: {file: File, preview: "...", name: "..."}
       length: 2
2 [{…}]0: {...SomeObject...}
       length: 1
```

Comment: it could be due to `setState` being asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

because you do it by reference - presumably pushing into `props.photos` in the parent component - and your child has that in `this.state.photos` - but you render it from state, not props. so the update won't be picked up / noticed until a change later.

either keep them in sync via `componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){ this.setState({photos: newProps.photos}) }` or just loop `this.props.photos` instead of having a local state and keep it stateless.

Comment: how this possible? he never calls setState in his component and never updates state, photos should always be empty

Comment: it's not empty. it's by reference. `this.state.phtotos = props.photos` in his constructor. if in parent he has `props={this.state.photos}` and in the `handleImage` he pushes into the photos array and sets state, it will also update the state by reference but not render. can easily test it via changing to `this.state.phtotos = props.photos.slice()` and nothing will come in.

Comment: yeah this probably only way photos could get there

Comment: thank you for help, but it remains the same. Problem is not in `this.state` or `this.props` they are updating according by `console.log()`, but why after doing `map()` on them, elements are 1 less then is `props`?